# setTimeout in IE8 with jquery jstween animation loop

Tags: jquery, animation, internet-explorer-8, settimeout, jstween

the following animation works just fine in chrome and firefox, but doesn't run in an infinite loop on IE8.
http://jsbin.com/acokus/5/edit

i think there is a problem with the setTimeout, or i've done something fundamentaly wrong..

Comment: Its not even animating once for me in IE8...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the solution:**

i don't know exactly why it's working now in IE8, but maybe it's helpful for someone who likes to program loops with jsTween:

http://jsbin.com/acokus/17/edit